# How can I have an abstract parent state know which child state is active?

Tags: angularjs

Using UI-router, I have an abstract parent state with 6 child states.  The child states are loaded using tabs on the parent state template.  Using `ng-class`, I want the active tab to be highlighted.  I can set a `$scope.active_tab` variable and change it every time the user clicks a new tab, but that won't work if a child state is navigated to directly via url.

Comment: Set ng-class based on $state.current.name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ui-sref-active directive, which allows you to add classes to an element when the related ui-sref state is active

```
<ul>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
    <!-- ... -->
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an abstract state that is the parent of other states, then the abstract state and its controller will be loaded **first**, then the child states will be loaded after the parent state has finished loading.

In the parent controller you can then listen for the $stateChangeSuccess event, and perform your logic there.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {
    // perform your logic here
});
```